How to append multiple .csv into one .csv (not multiple sheets .xlsx)?
Looking to do something like this:

Is there a script that can do that? I've tried searching and the scripts are either 404'ed or they merge them into a single .xlsx with multiple sheets.

But from your screenshots it looks like Excel.  .Csv are single sheet files. You can use Power Query to do this and save the files as .Csv again!

Sorry, not sure what you mean. I'm looking to do is merge multiple .csv with the same headings into one sheet.

I meant to say, .Csv files can have one sheet only, but your screenshot shows multiple sheets. To append multiple .Csv you can still use Power Query
